# Why allInstance not for isUnique?

Tags: ocl

I have a class Client with attribute noClient, I wan to verify there is no client with the same noClient.

I have the solution below, but the teacher said its not appropriate. Because the contraint may be repeated. I don't know why. And I need to find another solution.

```
context Client
inv NoClientUnique: Client.allInstances -> isUnique (noClient)
```

My problem is, I don't even know what is the problem with the code above to be able to find another solution.

This this a school question. Maybe not enough challenging out there, but I spend hours trying to understand. I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from minor syntactical mistakes (should be allInstances()-> ) I don't see a problem with your expression. Make sure you didn't misunderstood your teacher regarding what the constraint was supposed to constrain

Answer (score 0):

I just saw in an example, my teacher created a class Singleton, then use the Singleton as context, and not the Client.

```
class Singleton
-- nothing here.
end
...
context Singleton
inv SingletonisUnique : Singleton.allInstances -> size() = 1
inv noClientUnique : Client.allInstances -> isUnique(noClient)
```

I think this is the key to my problem, but I don't understand what's the mechanism there.

Comment: But `noClient` is not defined in the context of `Singleton`. Your example (question) means that there cannot be two instances of client with the same number. Your teacher's example could work if it were the postcondition of an operation `noClientUnique(noClient)`, but it doesn't work as an invariant of the Singleton.

Comment: Hi,

I gave it to the teacher, I follow his example.  I will ask him question later about this.  And reporting here, if i can understand what he said. :)

Thanks both for all your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher is correct in that with typical OCL tools evaluation of all Clients will be repeated for each Client.

But your teacher is also wrong in that a decent OCL tool should optimize the self-less invariant to achieve the same effect as the spurious Singleton. Tools should help the users not force users to manually optimize.

More realistically, the container of Client may perhaps be Business and you could more sensibly express the business practice that noClient is unique in Business since it isn't really a Client constraint.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, in a typing vision, the OclExpr in parameter should be a boolean expression to evaluate, which is not the case here.

Of course, the result will vary from one OCL tool to another.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be:

```
context Client
inv NoClientUnique: Client.allInstances()->forAll(c1, c2 : Client | c1 <> c2 implies c1.noClient <> c2.noClient)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for the answer in 2020:

```
Client.allInstances().collect(noClient) -> count(noClient) = 1
```

I'm using USE from Bremen University and the isUnique() operation does not work as intended. Took me awhile to figure out an alternative.