# How to specify the unique identifier of a Class

Tags: uml, class-diagram, ocl

I have to indicate for the Employee class that each employee can be clearly identified by his personal number. I do not know if I think too complicated, because I have no real idea.

Attributes:
final int personelNumber
...

Comment: Hello M.Schwarze, Please mark one of the answers as accepted, or explain what is still not clear to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need an OCL constraint to express that in UML.
There is a property `isID` on the Property metaclass that ensures this:

From UML 2.5 specification § 9.5.3 (p. 111)

> A Property may be marked, via the property isID, as being (part of)
>   the identifier (if any) for Classifiers of which it is a member. The
>   interpretation of this is left open but this could be mapped to
>   implementations such as primary keys for relational database tables or
>   ID attributes in XML. If multiple Properties are marked as isID
>   (possibly in generalizing Classifiers) then it is the combination of
>   the (Property, value) tuples that will logically provide the
>   uniqueness for any instance. Hence there is no need for any
>   specification of order and it is possible for some of the Property
>   values to be empty. If the Property is multivalued then all values are
>   included.

The notation for this property is similar to that of other constraints
using 
`{id}` after the name and type of the attribute

[image]

Comment: Correct, but UML does not specify a notation for this property, so how would you visualize the value of this property in a class diagram?

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl In fact the specs also specify a notation. I've edited my answer to include that.

Comment: Thanks. Which section of the UML spec describes this notation?

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl §9.5.4, on the same page. See `<prop-modifier>`

Comment: However, I assume that this {id} annotation makes it globally unique. What if you want local uniqueness along an association? For example, all names in a directory must be unique, but different directories may contain the same names. So, you have an association from DirNode to DirEntry, where DirEntry has a name: str.

Answer (score 2):

You don't provide your metamodel, and clearly wrt to each Employee their personelNumber is single valued and so necessarily unique. Presumably it is within some scope such as a Company that the personelNumber should be unique, so the answer is often something like.

```
context Company
inv UniquePersonelNumber: employees->isUnique(personelNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two alternative OCL expressions can be found in the following question:
[Why allInstance not for isUnique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22058510/why-allinstance-not-for-isunique)

In your case, it would be:

```
context Employee
inv personalNumberUnique : Employee.allInstances() -> isUnique(personalNumber)
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I will remove the UML part of my answer.